# Find the eigenvalues of $T$ for $T: M_{3x3}(\mathbb C)\to M_{3x3}(\mathbb C)$ such that $T(X)=Q\cdot X\cdot Q^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Suppose $T: M_{3x3}(\mathbb C)\to M_{3x3}(\mathbb C)$ such that $T(X)=Q\cdot X\cdot Q^{-1}$ and
$$Q=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c\end{array} \right)$$

Find the eigenvalues of $T$.

So I computed $$Q^{-1}=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{a} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{b} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c}\end{array} \right)$$

Then hence 
$$Q\cdot X\cdot Q^{-1}=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_{11} & \frac{a}{b}x_{12} & \frac{a}{c}x_{13} \\
\frac{b}{a}x_{21} & x_{22} & \frac{b}{c}x_{23} \\
\frac{c}{a}x_{12} & \frac{c}{b}x_{32} & x_{33}\end{array} \right)$$

But I'm stuck here. How do i get the transformation matrix $T$ from this?

Comment: Equate your result with $\lambda X$ and compare the entries

Comment: @akech wouldn't get result in $\lambda = \{1, \frac{a}{b}, \frac{a}{c}, \frac{b}{a}, \frac{b}{c}, \frac{c}{a}, \frac{c}{b}\}$?

Comment: Alternatively, T is diagonal with respect to the obvious basis of elementary matrices. You can read off eigenvalues in this case too.

Answer (score 2):

By some observation, we claim that the eigenvalues of ${\sf T}$ are $1$, $\frac{a}{b}$,
$\frac{a}{c}$, $\frac{b}{a}$, $\frac{b}{c}$, $\frac{c}{a}$, and $\frac{c}{b}$.
For example, consider $\lambda=1$, then take 
\begin{align}
X_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
X_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},\quad\mbox{and}\quad
X_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
we see that
$${\sf T}(X_i)=X_i,\quad\forall 1\leq i\leq 3.$$
For another example, consider $\lambda=\frac{a}{b}$, then take
$X=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$, we see that ${\sf T}(X)=\frac{a}{b}X.$ Thus, by following this path,
we may complete our claim. Furthermore, we have shown that
the standard ordered basis for ${\sf M}_{3\times 3}(C)$ consists of eigenvectors of ${\sf T}$, so ${\sf T}$ is 
diagonalizable.

Comment: Why is possible to make such an equivalence by just comparing the coefficients? I think actually thinking along the lines of the usually method $det(T-\lambda\cdot Id_3)=0$

Comment: Not $Id_3$, it should be $Id _9$. I just check that the seven coefficients satisfy the definition of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

So your eigenvalue equation is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & \frac{a}{b}x_{12} & \frac{a}{c}x_{13} \\
\frac{b}{a}x_{21} & x_{22} & \frac{b}{c}x_{23} \\
\frac{c}{a}x_{12} & \frac{c}{b}x_{32} & x_{33}\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda\,x_{11} & \lambda\,x_{12} & \lambda\,x_{13} \\
\lambda\,x_{21} & \lambda\,x_{22} & \lambda\,x_{23} \\
\lambda\,x_{12} & \lambda\,x_{32} & \lambda\,x_{33}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
You get nine equations. Three of them are $$x_{kk}=\lambda\,x_{kk}.$$Now, if one of $x_{11},x_{22},x_{33}$ is nonzero, we get $\lambda=1$.

If $\lambda\ne1$, then at least one of $x_{12}$, $x_{13}$, $x_{21}$, $x_{23}$, $x_{31}$, $x_{32}$ is nonzero (if they were all zero, $X=0$). Looking at each of the six possibilities we get the eigenvalues 
$$
\frac ab, \frac ac, \frac ba, \frac bc, \frac ca, \frac cb.
$$